# Multiplying 2 columns in excel using .write_formula (xlsxwriter) in python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

[I want to multiply columns "D" and "E" and write the answer in column "F"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoHcc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_formula).

This should be as easy as `worksheet.write_formula('F3', '=D3*E3')`. If you want to do it for your whole sheet, just write a loop like

```
for row in range(my_rows):
    sheet.write_formula('F{}'.format(row + 1),
                        '=D{}*E{}'.format(row + 1, row + 1))
```

You might want to omit the rows without data, but I guess, you know the correct indices.